# Django LeafletWidget custom style of geometry

Tags: javascript, css, django, django-forms, leaflet

I'm using django and leaflet for my app where I display gps tracks on a map. For my edit page of a gps track I use the [LeafletWidget](https://django-leaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widget.html#in-forms). Now I want to change the line style of this element.

```
#forms.py
class ActivityEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:  
        model = Activity
        fields = ('name', 'track_generalized', 'desc')
        widgets = { 
            'track' : LeafletWidget()    
        }
```

And here a part of my html:

```
  //activity_edit.html
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
```

Result:
[image]

I'm a beginner in front-end and css. But I don't want the default blue line for the track. I want to change it to a red line with bigger width.
In my normal map view I can change the style of the track on loading the tracks as geojson. But in the form it is already loaded and displayed and I don't know how to access the track to change its style.

**Edit**

Edit after looking at the link posted from iklinac in the comment.

```
#forms.py
class YourMapWidget(LeafletWidget):
    geometry_field_class = 'YourGeometryField'

class ActivityEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:  
        model = Activity
        fields = ('name', 'track_generalized', 'desc')
        widgets = { 
            'track' : YourMapWidget()    
        }
```

Then I add following to my javascript:

```
    window.addEventListener("map:init", function (event) {
      map = event.detail.map; // Get reference to map

      YourGeometryField = L.GeometryField.extend({
        addTo: function (map) {
            L.GeometryField.prototype.addTo.call(this, map);
            console.log(this);
        },
      });
     });
```

My output in the console is:
[image]

How can I change the color there? I tried following:

```
this.drawnItems._layers[Object.keys(this.drawnItems._layers)[0]].options.prototype.prototype.color = "red";
```

But it didn't work... I think the solution should be really easy, but I don't get it.

Comment: https://django-leaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widget.html#custom-forms

Comment: @iklinac thank you for the link. I tried to study the page in more detail and made an update to my post. But I don't get it...